# Short code inside the page not working in WordPress

Tags: shortcode

Ex.
I used a short code  [dropcap] I know you're better than me[/dropcap]
When I updated the page and view the website same is showing on page   [dropcap] I know you're better than me[/dropcap][image]

Comment: Is this shortcode part of a plugin, or does it come with your theme? If it's a plugin, can you let us know which one? Can you show us a screenshot of the shortcode in your WordPress editor please?

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot. No, it's not a part of plugin it comes with my theme. Let me tell you in others words, when I try to put short code into my page [visual/text view] I.e., [dropcap]content[\dropcap] ... same output get generates on website....

Comment: There are two options comes in every page of my theme I.e.,,1. Select short code drop-down list where you can select your short code 2. Choose your content and then 3.it will ask to generate short code via shortcode generator ...I don't know where it comes on my page... Please help me to resolve it now

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing further details of your specific installation:

1. Make sure you are actually previewing live on the web in a browser
   to see if the short-code actually is working.
2. Make sure you have spelled the short-code correctly, and have the correct syntax. (See theme's documentation.)
3. If the short-code requires some special JavaScript library, often other plugins that also use JavaScript, can interfere. I've had 3rd party plugins break the default theme functionality on my site.  When I deactivate the offending plugin, the theme features work again.
4. Contact the theme developer's support forum or directly for answers.  Likely others have the same issue or question.  If #1 or #2 or #3 above are not the issue, then the developer or other user in a forum may be able to shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a dropcap is reserved for a single character at the start of a sentence. I suspect that by putting a complete sentence into the dropcap shortcode 'output' area, you are confusing the code, and it may be the apostrophe (quote) within your sentence that is breaking it. Please try it again with a single letter ('I') and then enter the rest of your sentence after the dropcap shortcode in the text edit area. If this doesn't work, try adding a dropcap plugin (just search for 'wordpress dropcap plugin' and install one of those).